# Paypal api Insufficient permissions error on sale transaction

Tags: payflowpro

I'm using the Paypal Payflow api and receiving the following response error when trying to go live or in test:

`RESULT=52&PNREF=xxxxxxxxxxx&RESPMSG=Insufficient permissions to perform transaction`

From searching it seems there is a lot of people having issues with this. I also can't find error code 52 in any documentation that might help me resolve the issue. This thread explains the same unresolved issue: [Paypal forum](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/payflow-gateway/insufficient-permissions-error-sale-transaction)

Comment: I've called Paypal support a few times already about this and no one knows what a error code 52 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my clients account was signed up for Payments Advanced and not Payments Pro. The upgrade has to be done over the phone, the online form will tell you that the application has already been approved.